# try of my code works when the method is run on its own, but when I call the method when testing my program... catch errors appears

Tags: java, arraylist, try-catch, jakarta-mail, bluej

```
public static void sendMail(){

      Properties prop = new Properties(); 
      prop.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");
      prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
      prop.put("mail.smtp.starttles.enable", true);
      prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
      prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); 
      prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

       Session session = Session.getInstance(prop, new javax.mail.Authenticator()
      { 
       protected javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
       {
           return new javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication("testerkenan@gmail.com", "tester1234"); 
       }

     });

       Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
       cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
       SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
       System.out.println(cal.getTime());
       String formatted = format1.format(cal.getTime());
       ArrayList<Patient> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
           list = Arraycreate.Arraypatients();
           System.out.println(list.get(0).getName());
           System.out.println("list instiated");
           for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
               System.out.println("for loop works");
               if (list.get(j).getNext().getDay() == cal.getTime().getDay() && list.get(j).getNext().getMonth() == cal.getTime().getMonth()&& list.get(j).getNext().getYear() == cal.getTime().getYear()){
          System.out.println("if function works");
          /*
           try   {
           Message message = new MimeMessage(session);  
           message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("testerkenan@gmail.com"));
           message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("testerkenan@gmail.com"));
           message.setSubject("Follow up alert");

           MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
           messageBodyPart.setText("Good Morning Doctor, you have a follow up today with " + list.get(j).getName()); // enter message
           Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();  
           multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
           Transport.send(message);


           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Message Sent!");

           } catch(Exception e) {

           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Something Wrong With Email!");

            }*/
        }
        }
       }catch (Exception e){
           System.out.println(e);
```

I wanna send an email in my program so I created this method. I used System.out.println() and commented out the send email part to check if the each part is running and they are. However when applying the send email code. I get the catch error e and this output:

Thu Mar 09 13:07:17 GST 2017

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
```

and now that I have used the Arraylist in this mail method, I receive the catch error when I used it another method. The previous method worked perfectly before I attempted to call the list from the Arraycreate.Arraypatients() method that returns a sorted arraylist.

Comment: can you show exception

Comment: `Arraycreate.Arraypatients()` returns a list with fewer than 4 elements.

Comment: Welcome to SO. When posting error message, post a complete stacktrace, and mark the line where the stacktrace sais the error happened.

Comment: By the way, the common naming conventions in Java are that getters (which Arraypatients() obviously is) should be named "getPropertyname" - so in your case "getArraypatients()".

Comment: Arraycreate.Arraypatients() doesn't return a list of fewer than 4 elements, I use the same list in other classes and I have tested it by printing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is being thrown because of your instantiation of the ArrayList and since you have not shown your ArrayPatients function i cannot be sure but i think you should change:

```
ArrayList<Patient> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

to

```
ArrayList<Patient> list = null;
```

Comment: While your suggestion is ok, I don't think it has anything to do with the exception. He should change his for loop to `for int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++)`

Comment: What may be the problem in my for loop?